# How to run an app in background on jailbroken iphone?

Tags: xcode, background, jailbreak

I try to develop an app in XCode that runs in background. For example, the home splash screen or another app is shown on display and it is still running.

How do I do that?

The iphone is a jailbroken 3gs with IOS 5.1.1

Comment: This depends on what you wish to accomplish with your app. Do you want it to be an actual app with an icon and a gui that continues to run in the background (like Pandora), or do you want it to be a program that just runs in the background (like a server)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use theos to compile a dylib file,and start it by hook springboard.